# Can you mix agent action submission using `send` and `send-off` in Clojure? What is supposed to happen?

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I understand a Clojure "agent" is a `ref` with an added work queue of "actions". Actions are functions that are called with the `ref`'s value at first position and can be passed additional parameters. Actions return a new value for the `ref`. Thus an "agent" is a device which computes *ref := (action_[n] ° action_[n-1] ° action_[n-2] ° ... ° action_[1] ° action_[0]) (ref)*, likely with action-induced side-effects.

A call `(send-off agent action & args)` results in `action` being enqueued for asynchronous processing by a separate thread assigned by the system to the `agent` (from a growable thread pool, as I understand, and once the agent's queue is empty, the thread is either stopped or goes back into the pool).

A call `(send agent action & args)` results in `action` being enqueued for asynchronous processing by thread from a fixed system pool, where the thread is switched between actions belonging to multiple agents. In that case, the `action` should avoid blocking or hogging the thread for all too long.

So far so good, but what happens if some actions are enqueued with `send` and some with `send-off` to the same agent? Will the system switch between its two processing modes as it dequeues the action from the agent's queue?

Comment: FWIW it is not a `ref` in the technical sense, though of course it is a reference type. `ref`s have to implement retries to handle conflicting updates. An agent never has a conflict, because there is only ever one action operating on an agent at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between `send` and `send-off` is which thread group is used.  The scheduling of the agent and a thread is (must be) done separately.

The only reason there are 2 thread groups in the first place is so that the `send` can be used for "fast running" tasks (eg in-memory/non-network operations).  Tasks that are "slow" (e.g. network calls) are supposed to use `send-off` so they don't block the "fast" tasks.

The definition of "fast" and "slow" is vague and up to the user.  Notice the difference in language here for `send` vs `send-off` (for "potentially blocking actions" like disk or network I/O):

https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/send

---

More info here:   https://clojure.org/reference/agents

> The actions of all Agents get interleaved amongst threads in a thread
>   pool. At any point in time, at most one action for each Agent is being
>   executed. Actions dispatched to an agent from another single agent or
>   thread will occur in the order they were sent, potentially interleaved
>   with actions dispatched to the same agent from other sources. send
>   should be used for actions that are CPU limited, while send-off is
>   appropriate for actions that may block on IO.

Comment: Thanks for the spec quote: that's more definitive than any source-code link could be.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have `send` and `send-off` backwards: `send` uses a fixed-size threadpool, while `send-off` uses an unbounded threadpool.

But this makes no difference to the agent: actions are added to the agent's single queue, with a little note attached saying how they should be executed when the agent is ready to execute them. The agent always executes those actions sequentially, one at a time.

See for yourself: [`dispatch(IFn, ISeq, Executor)`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Agent.java#L234) forwards to `dispatch(Action)`, which forwards to `enqueue(Action)`.

Comment: Uh .. thanks you are right regarding the mix-up: I will fix that.